# Verify the map is well defined

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Verify that the map $L :CP^1 \rightarrow CP^1$ defined by,

$[z:w] \rightarrow [az+bw : cz+dw]$ ,

Is well defined.

Im stuck on how to start this question, or what I should be referring to.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: If you replace $(z,w)\mapsto (\lambda z,\lambda w)$, what happens with the output $(az+bw,cz+dw)\mapsto ???$

Answer (score 0):

Given a maps $g\colon Z\to X$ and $h\colon Z\to Y$, one may attempt to define a map $f\colon X\to Y$ as follows:

> For $x\in X$, pick $z\in Z$ with $g(z)=x$ and set $f(x)=h(z)$.

In general, this doesn’t actually define a function. The term „well-defined“ is used specifically to the case that the above method actually *does* define a function. For this to happen, two conditions are necessary and sufficient:

- The map $g$ must be onto.
- We must have $g(z_1)=g(z_2)\implies h(z_1)=h(z_2)$ for all $z_1,z_2\in Z$.

---

In your exercise, note that the definition is indeed of this type with $Z$ being two-dimensional space.